# A modification of the Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: graph, dijkstra

I need help.
Is there a way to modify this Dijkstra algorithm I found on the internet so that it also prints the number of branches between the source node and the other nodes that are reachable?

I tried to introduce some counter in the code when checking the connectivity between the nodes but without success.

```
int minDistance(Graph g,double dist[], bool sptSet[])
{
// Initialize min value
int min = INT_MAX, min_index;
for (int v = 0; v < g.n ; v++)
    if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
        min = dist[v], min_index = v;
    return min_index;
}
void printSolution(Graph g,double dist[])
{
    cout<<"Vertex Distance from Source\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < g.n; i++)
    if (dist[i] < g.n)
    {
        cout<< i+1 << "         " << dist[i] << endl;
    }
}
void dijkstra(GRAPH g, int src)
{
    double dist[MAX];
    bool sptSet[MAX];
    for (int i = 0; i < g.n; i++)
        dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptSet[i] = false;
    dist[src] = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < g.n - 1; count++) 
    {
        int u = minDistance(g, dist, sptSet);
        sptSet[u] = true;
        for (int v = 0; v < g.n; v++) {
            int c = 0; //Here I tried to introduce a counter!
            if (!sptSet[v] && g.ms[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX && 
                    dist[u] + g.ms[u][v] < dist[v])
            {
                c++; //Here I tried to introduce a counter!
                dist[v] = dist[u] + g.ms[u][v];
            }
             cout << c; //Here I tried to introduce a counter!
        }
    }
    printSolution(g, dist);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to fix your tagging.  This is a graph-theory question, not a graph question.  You also need to tag the coding language - looks like C or C++

Comment: "the number of branches"  Is this really what you mean?  Or do you mean the number of edges?

Comment: What is stored in dist[]?  Your code is incomplete, with no declaration of GRAPH ( among many other omissions ) so it is impossible to know.  In many dijsktra implementations it is used to store the hop count from source to every node.  If not in your case, then you will have to add a global alongside dirst[] that does store the hop count.